# Why does my terminal look like this?

Tags: command-line, scripts, nano

When I maximize the terminal, the display becomes like this and text won't expand to entire screen.  All the content/text is only visible on top left side of the window while it's maximized.

All the text should expand to full width of the terminal.How can I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean, looks quite normal to me.

Comment: Are you connected over `screen` ?

Comment: Hi @user3184235 Could you indicate if Wayne_Yux is right (below my answer)?  Will remove my answer if he is.

Comment: This is not normal. All the content/text is only visible on top left side of the window while it's maximized. All the text should expand to full width of the terminal.

Comment: @user3184235 see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Nano won't automatically resize to the new resolution. I.e. you need to exit and re-open nano, then it will fill the entire screen.

Comment: I can't exit. Because this terminal through a custom launcher. And that is not full screen by default...

Comment: And it's not only for nano. It's for usual command interface as well... and everything output of the programs.

Comment: The launcher may be specifying the terminal size. If thats the case resizing the window will not help.